# PHP - Counting Strings in Array

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know how to get the number of occurences of "photo" and "status"? I tried to output it as a string and perform a substr_count but no luck.

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => photo ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => photo ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => status ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => photo ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => photo ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => photo ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => status ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => photo ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => status ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => status ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => photo ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => status ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => status ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => photo ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => status ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => status ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => photo ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => photo ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => status ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => status ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => status ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => link ) 
Array ( [0] => [1] => status )
```

The original JSON code from the Facebook Graph API is:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "123", 
      "from": {
        "name": "Some Name", 
        "category": "Food/beverages", 
        "id": "123"
      }, 
      "picture": "a pic", 
      "link": "a link", 
      "name": "bla bla ", 
      "caption": "9 new photos", 
      "icon": "a icon", 
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "a link"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Like", 
          "link": "a link"
        }
      ], 
      "privacy": {
        "description": "Public", 
        "value": "EVERYONE"
      }, 
      "type": "photo", 
      "object_id": "232342", 
      "created_time": "2012-03-01T14:58:53+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2012-03-02T14:12:50+0000", 
      "likes": {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "a name", 
            "id": "1234423"
          }
        ], 
        "count": 58
      }, 
      "comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "234234", 
            "from": {
              "name": "a name", 
              "id": "23423234"
            }, 
            "message": "message bla bla", 
            "created_time": "2012-03-02T13:42:48+0000", 
            "likes": 2
          }, 
          {
            "id": "234234234", 
            "from": {
              "name": " a name", 
              "category": "Food/beverages", 
              "id": "123"
            }, 
            "message": "asfd", 
            "created_time": "2012-03-02T14:12:50+0000"
          }
        ], 
        "count": 15
      }, 
      "is_published": true
    }, 
    {
      "id": "123123", 
      "from": {
        "name": "name", 
        "category": "Food/beverages", 
        "id": "123"
      }, 
      "message": "sadfasfd", 
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "a link"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Like", 
          "link": "a link"
        }
      ], 
      "privacy": {
        "description": "Public", 
        "value": "EVERYONE"
      }, 
      "type": "status", 
      "created_time": "2012-03-01T09:49:40+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2012-03-01T17:00:53+0000", 
      "likes": {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "name", 
            "id": "1000"
          }
        ], 
        "count": 17
      }, 
      "comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "1404", 
            "from": {
              "name": "name", 
              "id": "1000"
            }, 
            "message": "bla bla", 
            "created_time": "2012-03-01T11:41:53+0000", 
            "likes": 2
          }, 
          {
            "id": "1404781", 
            "from": {
              "name": "name", 
              "id": "142"
            }, 
            "message": "message adsafasd", 
            "created_time": "2012-03-01T17:00:53+0000"
          }
        ], 
        "count": 9
      }, 
      "is_published": true
    },
```

I perform a json_decode with the JSON output and then loop through like that

foreach ($page_posts_overview->data as $page_posts_overview_output){

```
$type = " ".$page_posts_overview_output->type;
$type = explode(" ", $type);

$type = array($type);

print_r ($type);// this is what the output posted above
```

}

Comment: What is the original array structure?

Comment: Hi @zerkms 

The original output can be found here: https://graph.facebook.com/FANPAGEID/posts?since=2012-01-02&until=2012-03-02

Permissions needed but you can easily view it in the graph api explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

Comment: if you want your problem to be solved - you need to give as much information as it is needed. If you don't bother showing the actual array structure - no one won't.

Comment: hi @zerkms I edited the question. Thanks for having a look at it, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would need to loop through the array manually and keep count of the number of times each word shows up:

```
function count_words($fb_array) {

  $keywords = array();

  foreach($fb_array as $element) {
    $word = $element[1];
    if (!array_key_exists($keywords, $word)) {
      $keywords[$word] = 0;
    }
    $keywords[$word]++;
  }

  return $keywords;
}

print_r($keywords);
```

Assuming you have an array of keywords in `$fb_array`, `$keywords` should now contain a count for each word.

Comment: Hi @rjz, thanks a mil for that but unfortunately it doesn't print anything at all. Here is my code:
<?php 
foreach ($page_posts_overview->data as $page_posts_overview_output){
$type = " ".$page_posts_overview_output->type;
$type = explode(" ", $type);
$type = array($type);
print_r ($type);// this is what the output posted above 

}
function count_words($type ) {
  $keywords = array();
  foreach($type as $element) {
    $word = $element[1];
    if (!array_key_exists($keywords, $word)) {
      $keywords[$word] = 0;
    }
    $keywords[$word]++;
  }
  return $keywords;
}
print_r($keywords);
?>

Comment: Hey @GW, a little hard to tell from your code, but I think you're leaving `$type` hanging inside your first `foreach` rather than actually filling out the array? Instead of `print_r`ing each time through the loop, create a new array outside the loop and add each `$type` to the new array when you go through the loop. Then use the array you created outside of the loop in your call to `count_words`.

Comment: How about: `function count_words($fb_array, $index)` and then `$word = $element[$index];`?  This would make the function a little bit more generic.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array(...); // your Facebook data
$b = array();
foreach ($a as $e) {
   $b[] = $e[1];
}
$c = array_count_values($b);
var_dump($c)
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: Oh sorry, that's an error. At the end of the script, $c will contain an array of the occurrences for each string.